# Rasa init giving error :memoizationPolicy

Tags: python, anaconda, rasa-nlu, rasa-core, rasa

when I run

> Rasa init

command it gives an error

```
rasa.core.policies.ensemble.InvalidPolicyConfig: Module for policy 'MemoizationPolicy' could not be loaded. Please make sure the name is a valid policy
```

Kindly help me to resolve this issue.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/59916637/10088224. This is my answer to a similar question. You need a version of python that has support for TensorFlow. In my case 3.6 and TensorFlow version of 1.15.0 instead of 1.15.1.